# How to view source HTML from an InternetExplorer Object?

Tags: c#, .net

When I instantiate an IE object and navigate to a url, I don't know how to obtain the source HTML code from that address.

This is the code I'm using:

```
SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
IE.Visible = false;
IE.Navigate("www.testsite.com");
```

I want something like:

```
string source = IE.ToSource();
```

So I can inspect the content of it.
Can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try that:

```
SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
IE.Visible = false;
IE.Navigate("www.testsite.com");
mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 htmlDoc 
         = IE.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
string content = htmlDoc.body.outerHTML;
```

You can access the whole HTML string from the body.parent property:

```
string content = htmlDoc.body.parent.outerHTML;
```

[You can see a nice example here (the example in c++)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8923/Retrieving-the-HTML-source-code)