# Download the html source code to a string from a open website in IE with C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I been looking all over for this answer but can't find it anywhere..
This is what I want to be able to do:

I have a form application where i have a button that says "collect html code". When I press this button I want C# to download the HTML source code from the website I'm currently on (using IE). I've been using this code:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
string html = web.DownloadString("www.example.com");
```

But now I don't want to specify the URL in my code! And I don't want to use a webbrowser in my application.
Anyone got a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: If you don't specify a URL how are you going to download the HTML from no URL? Do you mean, you want to read it from a text box or something?

Comment: @DrSchizo - It's a question about querying IE for the current site.

Comment: there is a code for that on Channel9 forums: http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/157259-Urls-for-all-running-instances-of-IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code you can get IE7 and later version URL in opened tabs :

```
SHDocVw.ShellWindows allBrowsers = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();
foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ieInst in allBrowsers )
    {
        String url = ieInst.LocationURL;
        // do your stuff
    }
```

So you can access the urls and do your stuff with `WebClient` class.

You need to add a reference to a COM component called `Microsoft Internet Controls`

Comment: Nice solution! Though I've come across one more problem.. The URL doesn't change even though I ckick on a button and it shows new stuff on the page. Which results in the same html code is collected even though it looks different in the source.. Is there some way I can import the source directly and not the URL?

Comment: @elefantsko - are you looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780981/how-to-view-source-html-from-an-internetexplorer-object ?

Comment: YES!! Thank you so much Corak!

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about getting URLs from IE window? If so, here you are:

```
var urls = (new SHDocVw.ShellWindows()).Cast<SHDocVw.InternetExplorer>().
                Select(x => x.LocationURL).ToArray();
```

Don't forget to add COM reference "Microsoft Internet Controls" in your project.