# HTML Agility pack with ie COM object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, html-agility-pack

How can I take an open web page in IE, which was opened using PowerShell through COM, and do stuff with it using the HTML Agility Pack? Like

```
$myHtmlAgPackObj.LoadRawHtml($ie.Document.body)
```

perhaps???

It has to be from the COM object because I need to send keystrokes to the browser, so I can't just open the webpage with the agility pack.

Answer (score 2):

To get page's source HTML code from Internet Explorer COM object use :

`$IE.Document.body.parentElement.outerHTML`

Source: [How to view source HTML from an InternetExplorer Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780981/how-to-view-source-html-from-an-internetexplorer-object)

Barebone example:

```powershell
# Load HTML Agility Pack, assume it's alongside with the script
Add-Type -Path '.\HtmlAgilityPack.dll'

# Create new HTML Agility Pack document
$Hap = New-Object -TypeName HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument

# Create new Internet Explorer COM object
$IE = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application

# Navigate to page
$IE.Navigate('http://bing.com')

# Wait until navigation complete
while ($IE.Busy)
{
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

# Show Internet Explorer
$IE.Visible = $true

# Get page source
$Hap.LoadHtml($IE.Document.body.parentElement.outerHTML)

# Do some HTML processing
Write-Host "Document's first child attributes: $($Hap.DocumentNode.FirstChild.Attributes.Value)"

# Close Internet Explorer
$IE.Quit()

# Cleanup
Remove-Variable IE -Force
```